# No issue on old server but this error on new Server: The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: sql-server, iis, server

I have this error when i redeploy an app  on new server, However on old server or running my app locally it works just fine. are there settings in IIS or SQL server that i have to change or reinstall on the new server?

Comment: I suspect language settings and that you are using ambiguous `varchar` formats for a date and time data type. The solution is the find where the problem(s) occur and fix them (so that you don't use an ambiguous format). In SQL Server there are only 2 unambiguous formats: `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`

Comment: The problem occurs when you pass around date(time) values as *strings* rather than using a more appropriate data type. Ideally, you parse the string once, as early as possible after the user inputs it, and format it as late as possible when displaying it, and everywhere else use `DateTime` or `DateTime2` data types. You're getting this error because you force SQL to re-parse the date from a string.

Comment: Another possibility is you have varchar data that cannot be converted to datetime and the old/new execution plans are different, attempting the conversion earlier in the new server plan. You'll need to correct the data and, ideally, use correct data types.

Comment: The comments here, however, all come to the same conclusion; don't use a `varchar` to represent a date and time value. Use the date and time data types. The only time you should be using a `varchar` in SQL is at the initial assignment (for example `SET @Date = '20201124';`). Values from your application should already be the correct data type by the time that reach the SQL instance.

Comment: In addition to what is mentioned in the comments above, there may be another problem with database language settings. If English is set as your default language, SQL Server expects dates in MM/DD/YYYY format. Other languages may expect a DD/MM/YYYY format. SQL Server generates this error when there is a mismatch between what is provided and what the SQL Server is expecting.